# get an id of child element and store in a variable using jquery?

Tags: jquery, attributes, element

I'm basically trying to do exactly what the subject suggests, but I'm getting "undefined" in my alert, and I'm not entirely sure why.  I am fairly new to jquery, so, I probably have the syntax wrong, but not sure where to go from here.  I'll post both of my attempts, which both yield "undefined" in the alert...

```
//In my first attempt, I'm trying to get the id of the inner a tag
<ul>
                <li id="l1" class="active"><a href="#c1">Samp 1</a></li>
                <li id="l2" class=""><a href="#c2">Samp 2</a></li>
                <li id="l3" class=""><a href="#c3">Samp 3</a></li>
        </ul>

var selected = $(".active).children("a").attr("id");
    alert(selected);

//In my second attempt, I'm trying to get the id of the currently selected li
    var selected = $(".active").attr("id");
    alert(selected);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
$(".active").children("a").attr("id");
```

Your `<a>` elements do not have an `id`, only an `href`. And using a selector instead of the children function may make your code easier to read.

Do you mean `$(".active > a").attr("href")`?

---

```
$(".active").attr("id");
```

jQuery will return the `id` attribute of the first element in the jQuery collection. Do you have another element with class `active`?

I suggest you try `$("ul > li.active").attr("id")`

Answer (score 1):

In the first attempt, you're getting the `<a>` within the `<li>`...which doesn't have an ID, you just need this:

```
var selected = $(".active").attr("id");
alert(selected);
```

So your second attempt is correct, [you can see it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/VbNJZ/).

If you actually meant to get the `id` from the `<a>` element, then you need to give them IDs and your first attempt will work, [you can see it here](http://jsfiddle.net/VbNJZ/1/).

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the anchors seems to be that none of the anchors you're selecting actually have an ID. Do you mean `.attr("href")` by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the wrong attribute (or you have a wrong markup). There's no "id" attribute in your a tags. You have "href" attributes, so if you're trying to geth the value of "href" you should use this:

```
var selected = $(".active).children("a").attr("href");
    alert(selected);
```

Otherwise if you need to get the parent's id you should use:

```
var selected = $(".active).attr("id");
    alert(selected);
```

Comment: You're missing double quotes.